# Where .NET dll is looking for dependencies?

Tags: .net

I have a question regarding dependencies of .NET dll. How it's looking for them?
Only in GlobalAssemblyCache or in the local folder where is it?

To give bigger picture:
I am creating installers in InstallShield.

After building my project and installing product it seems that file ABC.dll is failed to register correctly.
I am checking it for dependencies in tool checkasm.dll and it shows that it's missing a dependency of file XYZ.dll.
When I copy file XYZ.dll to the same folder as file ABC.dll and rebuild the project it seems that file ABC.dll is correctly registered after installation.

Comment: This is too vague to stick a fork into.  How was the app that uses this DLL tested?  Making the installed version operate substantially different from the tested version is an extremely bad idea, DLL Hell burns.

Comment: I've just looking for registry entries after each installation. After first building of project and installation no registries for ABC.dll were present. After second (and adding XYZ.dll locally) build and installation registries were correct for ABC.dll.

But main question is:
How (or where) .NET dll is looking for it's dependencies?